# The ANTLR output and their order

Tags: java, antlr4

I got a small problem with the output of ANTLR.
Ive a realy small grammar which looks like this:

```
test   : states;
states : '.states' state+;
state  : stateID=ID {
     System.out.println("state: " + $stateID.text);
       | stateID=ID '{' state* '}' {
     System.out.println("SubState: " + $stateID.text);};
```

And what I want to parse looks like this:

```
a{
   b
   c{
      d
    }
}
```

Well, the problem is, the first token I'll get is 'b' followed by 'd' and then 'c'.
But my intention is to parse it into my datastructure and I need to know their parents.
What I know by this order is, c is the parent of d, but what about b?
If I rewrote the example to this form:

```
a{
   c{
      d
    }
   b
}
```

Everything is fine. So is there a way to know who is the parent of b, without having the constraint to write it in the last example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANTLR 4 using grammar-actions is no longer recommended. The parser may visit and test different rules and alternatives in unexpected orders, so unless you're adding error-handling code it's better to let the process run normally and then inspect the result.

So you let the parser create its tree, and then write a custom listener that will emit your `println` calls at each step. For example, suppose you're working with a grammar called `Foo`, so that and ANTLR autogenerates a `FooBaseListener` class.

So first you'd make something like:

```
public class PrintingFooListener extends FooBaseListener {
    @Override 
    public void enterState(FooParser.StateContext ctx)
    {
        // It is possible to get all sorts of token/subrule/text 
        // information from the ctx input, especially if you labeled 
        // the parser/lexer rules. 

        System.out.println("I entered State");
    }
}
```

Then use the `ParseTreeWalker` utility class to navigate through the parse tree with your visitor in-tow:

```
// Assume lexing, etc. already done before this point
ParserRuleContext<Token> tree = parser.myMainRule(); // Do parse

ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker(); // Premade utility class
PrintingFooListener listener = new PrintingFooListener(); // Your customized subclass 
walker.walk(listener, tree);
```

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of `ParseTreeWalker`. Just use `ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, tree);`